# Matplotlib memory leak when rendering MathText to get its bounding box

Tags: matplotlib, memory, tex

Calling `get_window_extent()` for MathText-contatining Text objects in a loop increases used memory, despite Text objects being removed. Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


fig = plt.figure()
renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
sample_text = ' '.join("${}$".format(random.random())
                       for _ in range(1000))
while True:
    # This wouldn't make memory usage grow:
    # text = sample_text

    # This wouldn't either:
    # text = ' '.join("{}".format(random.random())
    #                 for _ in range(1000))

    # But this does:
    text = ' '.join("${}$".format(random.random())
                    for _ in range(1000))
    # ...when combined with get_window_extent():
    plotted_text = fig.text(0, 0, text)
    plotted_text.get_window_extent(renderer)
    plotted_text.remove()
```

Any ideas why, and how it can be prevented?

Comment: Are you using tex (`usetex=True`) or MathText?

Comment: My bad, it's actually MathText. I've edited the post to reflect this. `rcParams[text.usetex]` is set to `False`.

Comment: I would do the following: Try if this is reproducible with the development version of matplotlib. If so, open [an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) about it.